# Table columns reactive to length of text inside CSS

Tags: css, html-table, width, column-width

I want all my columns to be responsives to the text inside of it.
Like on this picture :

[image: Columns are not equals]

Actually here is my `<style>` :

```
Table, {
Width: 100%}

th, td {
font-size:   2vw;
padding: 1px;
text-align: center;}

 tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #d50000}
```

I want my table to fill all the screen width, each column to be responsive to the text length (no fixed width column) The text centered. And between each column an equal space.

How should I do in the CSS part?

Answer (score 0):

You're describing the default behaviour of HTML tables... Try posting the complete code, maybe your table is not well formed, maybe there's something else in your CSS breaking stuff